# How do sites like LinkedIn efficiently show the relationship distance 1st,2nd and 3rd between users. can we do the same with neo4j cypher.?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, linkedin-api

### Friend Ship Tree:

A ---> B----> C ----> D -------> E -----> F

its a sample friendship tree created in Nep4j, witch is having 6 nodes and some relationship b/w them.

I'm having two questions here

1) I want to find level of connection(1st/2nd/3rd like linkedin) between A and D.

2) I want to display the shortest path between A and F (here a-b-c-d-e-f) using Cypher

Answer (score 1):

To get the level of connection you can use:

```
MATCH friendpath=(a:Person{name:'Pavan'})-[:KNOWS*..3]->(d:Person{name:'Mark'})
RETURN LENGTH(friendpath)
```

And the shortest path (documented [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html#_shortest_path)):

```
MATCH (a:Person{name:'Pavan'}),(f:Person{name:'John'}),
shortpath = shortestPath((a)-[*..15]-(f))
RETURN shortpath
```

Note that this path is constrained to 15 hops to try and stop the query taking forever.

Comment: Thank you very much JohnMark, this is what i'm looking for. I need much help. i'l will contact you when ever i'm having any doubt.